# Unable to get provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, provider

I have problem with getting the provider. I search for an answer but still i can't have the right answer. Please help me with this.
Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
package="com.ultramegatech.ey"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/LightTheme">
    <provider
        android:name="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider.ElementsProvider"
        android:authorities="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="PeriodicTableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/LightTheme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ElementListActivity"
        android:label="@string/titleElementList" />
    <activity
        android:name="ElementDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="EyPreferenceActivity"
        android:label="@string/titlePreferences" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

My Database Provider

```
package com.ultramegatech.ey.provider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
* ContentProvider for accessing the chemical element database.
* 
* @author Steve Guidetti
*/
public class ElementsProvider extends ContentProvider {
/* Provider authority */

public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.ultramegatech.ey.provider";

/* Uri matcher ids */
private static final int ELEMENTS = 1;
private static final int ELEMENTS_ID = 2;
private static final int ELEMENTS_NUMBER = 3;
private static final int ELEMENTS_SYMBOL = 4;
private static final int ELEMENTS_FILTER = 5;

/* Uri matcher */
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements", ELEMENTS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements/#", ELEMENTS_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements/n/#", ELEMENTS_NUMBER);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements/s/*", ELEMENTS_SYMBOL);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "elements/filter/*", ELEMENTS_FILTER);
}

/* SQLiteOpenHelper */
private DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder) {
    final SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ELEMENTS:
            qb.setTables(Elements.TABLE_NAME);
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_ID:
            qb.setTables(Elements.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.appendWhere(Elements._ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_NUMBER:
            qb.setTables(Elements.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.appendWhere(Elements.NUMBER + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_SYMBOL:
            qb.setTables(Elements.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.appendWhere(Elements.SYMBOL + " = ");
            qb.appendWhereEscapeString(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_FILTER:
            qb.setTables(Elements.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.appendWhere(Elements.NAME + " LIKE ");
            qb.appendWhereEscapeString(uri.getLastPathSegment() + "%");
            qb.appendWhere(" OR " + Elements.SYMBOL + " LIKE ");
            qb.appendWhereEscapeString(uri.getLastPathSegment() + "%");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI: " + uri.toString());
    }

    final SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null,
            sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ELEMENTS:
        case ELEMENTS_FILTER:
            return Elements.DATA_TYPE;
        case ELEMENTS_ID:
        case ELEMENTS_NUMBER:
        case ELEMENTS_SYMBOL:
            return Elements.DATA_TYPE_ITEM;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    String table;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ELEMENTS:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI");
    }

    final SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final long rowId = db.insert(table, null, values);
    if(rowId > 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, rowId);
    }

    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri.toString());
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    String table;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ELEMENTS:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_ID:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            final String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if(selection == null) {
                selection = Elements._ID + " = " + id;
            } else {
                selection += " AND " + Elements._ID + " = " + id;
            }
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_NUMBER:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            final String number = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if(selection == null) {
                selection = Elements.NUMBER + " = " + number;
            } else {
                selection += " AND " + Elements.NUMBER + " = " + number;
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI");
    }

    final SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int rowsAffected = db.delete(table, selection, selectionArgs);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsAffected;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    String table;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ELEMENTS:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_ID:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            final String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if(selection == null) {
                selection = Elements._ID + " = " + id;
            } else {
                selection += " AND " + Elements._ID + " = " + id;
            }
            break;
        case ELEMENTS_NUMBER:
            table = Elements.TABLE_NAME;
            final String number = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            if(selection == null) {
                selection = Elements.NUMBER + " = " + number;
            } else {
                selection += " AND " + Elements.NUMBER + " = " + number;
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI");
    }

    final SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int rowsAffected = db.update(table, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsAffected;
}
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

> 02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.ultramegatech.ey.provider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.ultramegatech.ey.provider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ultramegatech.ey-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ultramegatech.ey-1,
>   /system/lib]]
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4366)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.ultramegatech.ey.provider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ultramegatech.ey-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ultramegatech.ey-1,
>   /system/lib]]
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4759)
>       02-12 06:00:42.041: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):   ... 12 more
>       02-12 06:00:54.471: I/Process(1245): Sending signal. PID: 1245 SIG: 9

My .sql is on the raw folder if it has regards with the problem.
I just get the code in gitHub and i will modify it for my thesis. Thanks and your answers will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you found a solution? Facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in below 2 lines :

```
    android:name="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider"
    android:authorities="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider.ElementsProvider"
```

they should be the other way around :

```
android:name="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider.ElementsProvider"
android:authorities="com.ultramegatech.ey.provider"
```

Also change the `authority` in the provider class. The `android:name` should point to the class name and not just the package. The `authority` can be the package name or anything else.

Comment: I did it but still it didn't work. What's wrong? Thanks for further information. Godbless.

Comment: I see you updated the code and the logs in the question based on this. But the error in the log still says  Didn't find class "com.ultramegatech.ey.provider" . (I assume you already tried clean build). Its still not looking for ElementsProvider but the package as class name

Comment: Yes. ,. I did what you say but it didn't worked. What can i do? Thanks a lot for your answer. It would be very helpful. Thanks.. Immediate answer will be higly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work now. Does it work with "exported=true" ?

Comment: Not either. Does the provider need to have any library?

Comment: No it does not need library

Comment: Does the targetsdk version affects the code for content provider?

Comment: Nope. It should not (At least to my knowledge)

Comment: Check if its a compile issue - not sure what you are using to compile .Check if  the dex file for ElementsProvider in your .apk correctly ?

Comment: What do you mean by that po? I am using eclipse adt bundle.

Comment: The src folder is empty but there's a folder named "java", Is this a source of error?